# Wildfly Version 23 Error While Deployment of a WAR and not able to configure a component

Tags: java, rest, soap, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to access a document file in order to configure the component, I have given the access in user.home directory as well but the file is not getting access and it shows this error :

{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit."JbossTest.war".INSTALL" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "JbossTest.war"
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0024: Could not configure component com.Service
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}

I tried all other ways to expose the folder with the xml and properties components, but its still the same error..

Suggestions would be appreciated and solution would be great if you have faced some similar issue

Comment: What does the code look like for trying to retrieve the file?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? I am also stuck in same while upgrading my application to wildfly 22